# Parallel processing in multiple instances of spring boot application

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, multiple-instances

I am not able to analyse, how to go ahead. I am using Spring boot 2, Oracle, IBM MQ.

I have made 2 async requests to external applications. I need to do some operation when I have received both of the responses.

I am not able to set it up as there are multiple instances of application running and listening to same queue for response.

I tried using @transactional and cyclic barrier. But I guess they will work only in scope of their own instance and not between multiple instances.

How should I proceed ahead?

It is also really difficult to reproduce the scenario where one message is read by one instance and other by other instance that too at the same time, where they eventually try to update db at same time.

Comment: Your use case requires co-ordination between different processing instances and in that case you generally require a distributed lock. There are multiple ways to create it - one way you can do that is explained here using Redis https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/spring-boot-2.x-implementation-of-a-simple-distributed-lock.html

Comment: Also Spring Boot Redis integration provides easy way to create such a lock. You can refer here https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/spring-boot-redis-implements-distributed-locks-it-s-delicious.html

Comment: Also this distributed lock implementation gives you option of using a database as well for lock ( if you cannot use redis) https://github.com/alturkovic/distributed-lock